# The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE web module specification

Tags: eclipse

> The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE web module specification.

I am getting this error when I execute an application in Eclipse IDE. What is the reason for this?

Comment: You can set the servlet version during creation of a new dynamic web project:
http://eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/SchoolSchedule/images/webapp8.gif

Answer (score 23):

right click on your `project -> Properties --> project Facets` 
then you must change `Dynamic Web Module` from `3 to 2.5`

Comment: I am also coming to this question, but it seems this operate doesn't success

Comment: It depends if your project doesn't use 3.0

Answer (score 9):

The error message is quite understandable - you are attempting to execute an application that requires the server to support Servlet Spec 3.0 when it doesn't. You must therefore run the application on a server that complies with that version of the Servlet Specification.

As far as I know you have the following options at your disposal, at the time of writing this:

- Apache Tomcat 7.0
- Glassfish 3.1
- IBM WebSphere 8
- JBoss 6 and 7
- Resin 4

Answer (score 2):

The ...serverdef and plugin.xml configuration files for the server that you've set up in Eclipse define what versions of the specifications that the server supports.

Answer (score 1):

From you web project try to downgrade the `Dynamic Web Module`: project -> Properties -> project Facets

If this has no effect, try to downgrade the `EAR` from your EAR project: project -> Properties -> project Facets

If you can't change the versions from eclipse, edit manually the file `org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`

Answer (score 0):

1.Right Click on Project
2.Click on Build Path
3.Search for Project Facets
4.Change Dynamic Web Module version to `2.5`

This worked for me.

Comment: changing the dynamic web module version to 5.0 fixed my problem: