# The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss5.x

### The server does not support version 3.0 of the J2EE Web module specification.

I am getting this error when I am publishing my module in jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6.
I have read all the solutions on google as well on stackoverflow, but didn't get the proper solution.

Comment: Apparently you are trying to deploy a module that declares 3.0 as the version of the servlet API. This version is not supported in JBoss 5.1. So you can either upgrade to JBoss 7.1.1, or "fix" the WAR that you deploy. In the latter case, post some more information on your project setup so that people can help you. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922391/the-server-does-not-support-version-3-0-of-the-j2ee-web-module-specification

Comment: I have replaced Servlet-api 3.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to use the version of the servlet spec that your JBoss server supports, or to use a version of the JBoss server that supports version 3.0 of the servlet spec. You're trying to use a brand new version of the spec with an old server that was released when this version of the spec didn't even exist.

See https://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS for a matrix of JBoss versions and servlet spec versions.

Comment: Let me downlaod the newer version of the JBOSS.