# The server does not support version 3.1 of the J2EE Web module specification on Eclipse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Anybody facing the same problem? When I try to change the Dynamic Web Module version, eclipse does not allows me to.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6923199/3886428):

Quoting the same:

> The error message is quite understandable - you are attempting to execute an application that requires the server to support Servlet Spec 3.0 when it doesn't. You must therefore, run the application on a server that complies with that version of the Servlet Specification.
>
> As far as I know you have the following options at your disposal, at the time of writing this:

---

```
Apache Tomcat 7.0 
Glassfish 3.1 
IBM WebSphere 8 
JBoss 6 and 7
```

Comment: I am actually running the project on Apache TomCat 8. Everything runs fine. My boss wants it to run on WebLogic. When I try to choose the WebLogic server this errors pops up in Eclipse mentioning "The server does not support version 3.1 of the J2EE Web module specification". And when I try to change it to version 2.5 from the project facets, it does not allows me to.

Comment: Which weblogic Server are you using? and is it running on Java EE 7?

Comment: It's 12c(12.1.3) and it is Java EE 7.

Comment: Try this [link]http://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-cannot-change-version-of-project-facet-dynamic-web-module-to-3-0-error-in-eclipse/

Comment: Thanks @Dextrox67 . I found the error. the pom.xml file has mentioned auto detection of javaee-api on the dependency. And i edited it to version 6. The project facet now gave me an option to choose. I had to uncheck the Java Server Faces and lower the java version to 1.7. It worked!